# Including variables from a child template

Tags: jinja2

I have several templates:

**parent.jinja2**

```
{# Header #}

{% block content %}

{% block title_header %}
<h1>{{ the_title }}</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block child_content %}
{% endblock %}

{% include 'extra.jinja2' %}

{% endblock %}

{# Footer #}
```

**extra.jinja2**

```
{% block extra %}

<p>The title was {{ the_title }}.</p>

{% endblock %}
```

**child.jinja2**

```
{% extends 'parent.jinja2' %}

{% set the_title = "Title of doom" %}

{% block child_content %}
<p>Some stuff.</p>
{% endblock %}
```

When I render `child.jinja2`, the value of the `the_title` in `extra.jinja2` is empty. How can I access the value of `the_title` that is defined in `child.jinja2`?

The problem seems to go away if I remove the `title_header` block, so looks to be something to do with first reading `the_title` inside that block.

Comment: Works for me. I'm on Jinja 2.7.3. I assume your file is actually named `parent.jinja2`, right?

Comment: Oops, I forgot to add a block; updated. Yes it is named `parent.jinja2`. I'm using Jinja 2.7.2 so I'll have a look at the changelog and see if that explains it.